# Extract number from a string in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have several columns that I want to extract the numbers from a string. I have this example:

[image: My input]

I've tried this code to extract the number for both columns:

```
df1 = df['Diatom col', 'Cistos col'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

But it's not working.

And that's the ouput I need:

[image: Output]

Comment: `\d+` matches any sequence of digits, it doesn't match `,`

Comment: but i applied the str.extract for one column and it worked. My problem is that it doesnt work for more than one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

If you post a data as a text or code, I'll be able to share the result.

Assumption: all numbers are together and not interspersed with non-digits, with exception of , and .

```
# replace out all characters that are not digits or comma or period.


(df[['Type','Size']]
 .apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[^\d\.,]','', regex=True) , axis=1)
 .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I applied to my data and it gave me the output i want